# Concencrate more cells in VBA with 'separator'

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I am trying to generate map from GCmap.com using the VBA code.
I do have a long list of airport pairs in one column. The format of the hyperlink that will generate the map will be:

"http://www.gcmap.com/map?P="&(calue in .cell(1.51))&"%0d%0a"&(calue in .cell(2.51)& so on ...

' the %0d%0a - is a separator that needs to be between values

the problem is that this list is a quite long and just doing simple loop will cause enormous length of hyperlink  (sometimes too long to generate the map) so it must be something like 
if valueOfFirstCell = ValueOfCellBellow then
' skip to next one

I've tried this (probably worst ever written code, but please note that I am only beginner in VBA :)

```
Sub hyperlinkgenerator()

Dim separator As String  ' declared the 'separator' value
separator = "%0d%0a"
Dim datarow, irow As Integer
Dim myval as Range

With Sheets("Direct flights")

   Set myval = .Cells(datarow, 51)

   Do While myval <> ""     ' do until last empty row

Dim Value1 As String
Value1 = Sheets("Direct flights").Cells(datarow, 51) ' declare value of the first cell

Dim Value2 As String

Value2 = Sheets("Direct flights").Cells(datarow + 1, 51) ' declare value of cell bellow

If Value1 = Value2 Then

datarow = datarow + 1

Else: 'enter Value1 in hyperlink that is followed by & separator
'also the hyperlink must start with: http://www.gcmap.com/map?P=
' and end with %0d%0a&MS=wls&MR=540&MX=720x360&PM=* 

End If

datarow = datarow + 1

Loop

End With

End Sub
```

The final link will look like:

http://www.gcmap.com/map?P=LGW-AMS%0d%0aAMS-LHR%0d%0aLCY-AMS%0d%0aLUX-AMS%0d%0aBRE-AMS%0d%0aCWL-AMS%0d%0aNUE-AMS%0d%0aAMS-JFK%0d%0a&MS=wls&MR=540&MX=720x360&PM=*

I don't have a clue how to keep loop adding new and new text into Hyperlink. Also hyperlink should be generated by and opened once user will click on button (that is easy to do).

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens when you run the code you've provided? Does it run OK? If not, what happens?

Comment: well, it is not finished, as I do not have a clue how to :D the Else statement in If is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub hyperlinkgenerator()
    Dim thisVal As String
    Dim nextVal As String
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim hyperlink As String

    currentRow = 1 ' or whatever the first row is
    hyperlink = ""

    With Sheets("Direct flights")
        Do While True
            thisVal = .Cells(currentRow, 1).Value
            nextVal = .Cells(currentRow + 1, 1).Value

            If thisVal = "" Then
                Exit Do
            ElseIf thisVal <> nextVal Then
                hyperlink = hyperlink & thisVal & "%0d%0a"
            End If

            currentRow = currentRow + 1
        Loop

    End With

    hyperlink = "http://www.gcmap.com/map?P=" & hyperlink & "&MS=wls&MR=540&MX=720x360&PM="

    MsgBox hyperlink
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh, I had set the "column" to "1" for testing, make sure you use the correct column (51 I believe)

Comment: it was actually column 58, but doesn't matter

Comment: to open it with Google Chrome I've replaced the MsgBox with:        
    Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -url " & hyperlink)